On the Existence of Continuous Versions of Stochastic Processes
Let $g(t, x)$ be a continuous function on an open set $S \subseteq [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $X_t(x)$ be an $\mathbb R^d$ valued random field where $t \in [0,T]$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ which is almost surely continuous as a function of $(t, x)$.
Suppose that $$\textbf{(1)} \qquad \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{\partial S} (t, X_t(x))dt \right]  = 0$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. I want to know if this is enough to conlude that there exists a continuous (in $(t,x)$) version/modification of the random field $$A_t(x) \equiv \int_0^t \mathbf{1}_S(s, X_s(x))g(s, X_s(x)) ds.$$
$\textbf{(1)}$ implies that $$\mathbb{P}\Big( A \text{ is continuous at } (t,x) \text{ for every } t \in [0,T]\Big) = 1$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (since $\textbf{(1)}$ implies that for Lebesgue almost every $s \in [0,T]$, $(s, X_s(x)) \in S \cup \text{int}(S^c)$, almost surely, for the fixed value of $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$) but this is not enough to conclude the existence of a continuous version, since there are uncountably many such $x$. We can of course conclude that there exists a version which is continuous at Lebesgue almost every $(t,x) \in [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$. This still is not enough of course.
Any help would be massively appreciated.
If it helps, suppose further that $$dX_t(x) = b(t,x, X_t(x))dt + \sigma(t,x,X_t(x))dW_t $$
with $X_0(x) = h(x)$. Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $b$,$\sigma$ and $h$ are all globally bounded and Lipschitz continuous (so that there exists a modification/version of the mapping $(t,x) \mapsto X_t(x)$ which is continuous almost surely). One can also assume $$\sigma(t,x,y) \sigma(t,x,y)^T \succcurlyeq \epsilon I$$ where $\epsilon > 0$.
